# How to ensure a field value is never used again even if it is deleted?

Tags: postgresql, unique, primary-key, sql-delete

I'm using postgres and I require a secondary key or a similar concept. I make full use of the primary key the id field. In addition to the primary key, I'm generating a useful 'conversational id' such as 'OH-15-001'.

I would like to ensure, that the above secondary key, is used only once even if is destroyed by the database. I've created an algorithm to generate these id's but I do not wish to save them in another table. I'm wondering if there is a feature in Postgres to ensure the field is unique, even if it is removed? (similar to the id field)

Comment: The only thing I can think of: don't really delete those rows, but just mark them as deleted (and e.g. create a view that filters them out)

Comment: Thats exactly what I decided. If you write that I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `PRIMARY KEY` doesn't ensure uniqueness against removed previous values. You will always get a new, unique ID if you generate them from a sequence, but nothing is preventing you from manually inserting a record with a previously deleted ID.

Can you use a sequence as part of your ID generation algorithm? (that, plus a `UNIQUE` constraint will behaving exactly the same as a primary key)